# Передача данных из AJAX в php

Tags: ajax, php, переменные

Здравствуйте.

Написал скрипт динамического обновления и понял, что ничего не выйдет, если не передать 1 php скрипт

AJAX:

```
function show()  
{  
    var id = <?php echo $_GET[id]; ?>;
    $.ajax({  
        url: "/obr/wallGroup.php?id=5",  
        cache: false,  
        success: function(html){  
            $("#content").html(html);  
        }  
    });  
}

$(document).ready(function(){  
    show();  
    setInterval('show()',1000);  
});
```

Мне надо передать переменную id в файл обработчика.

PHP:

```
echo $id;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 url: "/obr/wallGroup.php?id="+id,
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $_GET["id"]
```